# Error message: "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: php, eclipse

I have Eclipse PDT and Xampp, but when i try to run even the simplest script i get the object not found page. `http://localhost/test5` Apache web server is up and running. from my search i think i need to map Apache server to a particular directory. but i don't know how to do that. I cannot save my projects in XAMPP htdocs folder, so i had to save it in a new workplace. Can anyone help me please. its been a hassle downloading eclipse and now the last thing trying to get it to work.

Comment: Is your server configured well? You have to give more information.We cannot guess how your application looks like...

Comment: This isn't a specific programming problem, so voted to close. Also: try copying the files to the htdocs folder, or create a symlink, or change the rewrite rules, create vhosts.... there's a ton of options open for you

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem how do i create a symlink? thnx

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this??

Comment: @user2651231: `ln -s /some/real/dir symlink/location` on *NIX systems, `mklink /D symlink\location Real\Dir` on windows... you could've asked google that question, you know...

Comment: why does my post always get rated down. there are hundreds of questions like these

Comment: @user2651231: [check the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) your question doesn't fit the description of a good SO question: it doesn't contain any source-code, doesn't show us what you've tried to solve the problem yourself, it doesn't provide sufficient info to help you. You're also asking about apache settings, for which there is an other stack-exchange site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, xampp's apache looks into c:\xampp\htdocs

But you should have the habit to create virtual hosts for your projects. Open c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, and place this into it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/Eclipse/workspace/your-project/"
ServerName your-project
<Directory C:/Eclipse/workspace/your-project/>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then open your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and add your-project entry:

```
127.0.0.1 your-project
```

Restart apache and you can browse to `http://your-project/`